# Why are people voting to close "probability and infinity"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

What is the justification for voting to close [Probability and Infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5340/probability-and-infinity)?

**Please explain why if you are downvoting this**

Answer (score 4):

I was the first to vote to close, and I was hasty.  As I reread the question I realized that there was a reasonable way to address the OP's confusion, but I could not take back the vote.